# Split an alphanumeric string after each sequence of numbers

Tags: php, regex, split, text-parsing, preg-split

I have a series of strings in the form of

```
10a99b5c
55
2a3b1
g
```

How can I split the string by the characters (which always appears as a single character between numbers or in the beginning/end of the string)

```
array([0] => 10a99b5c, [1] => 10, [2]=> a99, [3] => b5, [4] => c),
array([0] => 55, [1] => 55),
array([0] => 2a3b1, [1] => 2, [2] => a3, [3] => b1),
array([0] => g, [1] => g),
```

The output format is not important, I can handle, I just have no idea what sort of regex pattern can do the trick (even a hint is sufficient).

I do this with `preg_replace_callback` where I use the digits found for each character for a set of calculations.

Comment: Could you add what you've tried so far ?

Comment: @Nicolas as I mentioned, I am looking for a hint to begin with. I have no clue what can match the existing and missing elements.

Comment: The hint is: https://regexr.com/  

Comment: another hint: https://regex101.com/r/Ox4yUh/1

Comment: @Luuk Wonderful, I got what I needed. If you post it as an answer, an accepted answer may help other people too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$input = ['10a99b5c','55','2a3b1','g'];
$regEx = '~([a-z]\d*)~';

foreach($input as $str){
  $res[] = preg_split($regEx,$str,-1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
}
echo '<pre>';
var_export($res);
```

The result for the examples above:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => '10',
    1 => 'a99',
    2 => 'b5',
    3 => 'c',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => '55',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => '2',
    1 => 'a3',
    2 => 'b1',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    0 => 'g',
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression:

> /[a-z]*[0-9]*/

- [a-z] will match any (lower-case) character
- - zero, or more times
- [0-9] will match a number
- - zero, or more times

https://regex101.com/r/Ox4yUh/1

Comment: Please note that this regex will also match `aaaaaaa10` i'm not sure if that's what you were looking for

Comment: This Googlebot is only interested in an answer, not in the `why`...., so who cares...     But indeed the first '*' should be a '?'.

Answer (score 0):

Your task is simple, split on the zero-width position after each sequence of numbers.

`$array = preg_split('/\d+\K/', $string, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);`

Match the digits with `\d+`, then release them with `\K` so that the numbers are not "consumed" during the explosion.

I'll bundle your four sample strings into an array of test strings.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/N0hCs))

```
$strings = [
    '10a99b5c',
    '55',
    '2a3b1',
    'g',
];

var_export(
    array_map(
        fn($string) => preg_split('/\d+\K/', $string, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY),
        $strings
    )
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => '10',
    1 => 'a99',
    2 => 'b5',
    3 => 'c',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => '55',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => '2',
    1 => 'a3',
    2 => 'b1',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    0 => 'g',
  ),
)
```